# can not upload the file with its extension and original path name using Multer and Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer, ng-file-upload

I have one issue while uploading the file using Multer module from Node.js.I am explaining my code below.

> server.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './upload/' });
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'images', maxCount: 1}]);
var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.post('/uploadAll',cpUpload,function(req, res, next){
    console.log('fiels',req);
})
```

> supplierController.js:

```
var file=fileURL;
var curnum=(Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
var newPicpath=curnum+"_"+ file.name;
file.name=newPicpath;
console.log('file',file);
$scope.upload=Upload.upload({
    url: '/uploadAll',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
            images: file,
        },
    headers : {
             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },

}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
}).error(function(data, status) {
        console.log('err file',data);
})
```

inside console message i am getting the below file data.

```
Blob
$ngfName:"vse123ertgf_1.jpg"
name:"vse123ertgf_1.jpg"
size:8607
type:"image/jpeg"
```

Here you can check my file name is containing one random number with it.When i am uploading the file the file is uploaded inside the given folder but taking another random number(`i.e-75149c6770ea216b5ad8aafa7698539d`) as its name and without extension(`i.e-.jpg or png`).Here also i am getting the error response inside error function in client side.I am using `ng-file-upload` to upload the file.Here i need the file should upload inside the required folder using its original name what its taking in client side.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Satya. The issue you are facing is very common. Please read the following [post](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/170) for some beautiful insight. I had the same issue and I resolved it using this post. For further issue please comment below, will help you out.

Comment: Ok,I will try this and infirm you.Thanks.

Comment: Did that work? If please mark the answer If no, ask further doubts.